# How does Alien Blue put a link to their app on Facebook.com posts?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to figure out how Alien Blue, a Reddit App for iPad and iPhone, puts a link to their app after the comment link on Facebook posts.  Here is a picture of what I'm referring to:

[image: Alien Blue Link to App "Get Alien Blue"]

It's the link with text of "Get Alien Blue" that links directly to their website.

Comment: Most likely they're digging through the facebook html, looking for that particular part of a page and inserting the link into the page's DOM. Since it's displaying the page, it's acting as a brower and can act as the equivalent of a Firefox greasemonkey script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a simple parameter in their API when you post a message.

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/
it's the `actions` parameter.